# No method or field annotated by @DynamoDBHashKey within type java.lang.String

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nosql, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

I don't know why doesn't run this project.

```
@Data
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "tableName")
public class entityName implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    private String rk;

    private String sy;
}

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method or field annotated by @DynamoDBHashKey within type java.lang.String!
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBHashAndRangeKeyMethodExtractorImpl.<init>(DynamoDBHashAndRangeKeyMethodExtractorImpl.java:99) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.CompositeIdHashAndRangeKeyExtractor.<init>(CompositeIdHashAndRangeKeyExtractor.java:31) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBHashAndRangeKeyExtractingEntityMetadataImpl.getHashAndRangeKeyExtractor(DynamoDBHashAndRangeKeyExtractingEntityMetadataImpl.java:71) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBIdIsHashAndRangeKeyEntityInformationImpl.<init>(DynamoDBIdIsHashAndRangeKeyEntityInformationImpl.java:49) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBEntityMetadataSupport.getEntityInformation(DynamoDBEntityMetadataSupport.java:125) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:104) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getDynamoDBRepository(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:128) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.support.DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(DynamoDBRepositoryFactory.java:150) ~[spring-data-dynamodb-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: try to ask a question in details.

Comment: Code formating.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is this bit:

```java
@DynamoDBRangeKey
private String rk;
```

I noticed that you have an `@Id` annotation, which means you probably have a Spring Data Repository looking something like this:

```java
@Repository
@EnableScan
public interface ServiceItemRepository extends CrudRepository<ServiceItem, String> {
}
```

The `@Id` annotation is a signal to Spring Data that this is the subject of the `String` generic in the Repository declaration. But composite keys seem to confuse the hell out of things. Basically, if you either remove the `@Id` and don't use a Repository here, or replace the `@DynamoDBRangeKey` with an ordinary `@DynamoDBAttribute`. You'll find things starting to work again.

BTW: Lombok had nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @michael-coxon the issue is with composite keys. Therefore, you would need to create a composite key class as described here.

https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki/Use-Hash-Range-keys

Answer (score 0):

You have to have getters and setters for the field, as in the documentation is stated:

> If the annotation is applied directly to the class field, the corresponding getter and setter must be declared in the same class.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBHashKey.html

Also have a look at the developer guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBHashKey

Comment: Did you notice the Project Lombok annotation `@Data`? I think the OP would have thought that the getters and setters would have been supplied by the generated accessors. Its interesting that this is not being recognised.

Comment: Lombok should have generated the accessors before runtime, so effectively, the corresponding getter and setter are being declared in the same class.

Comment: Then one has to check if these getters (and setters) exist before the AWS annotations are examined.

Comment: I was meaning to answer this, which I have just done - it turns out that the getters and setters weren't the problem, but its still a bit weird that it doesn't work. I mean I know the basic cause, but not the root cause.